# Free Modem Dialer

Tags: modem, phone-call

Is there a telephone application for modems that can receive a phone number as a parameter and manage the call for themselves? I ask because in my application I must implement a click2call functionality and may be is a free software out there that I can use and I do not have to fight with TAPI. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305692/how-to-dial-phone-number-using-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few wrappers available to abstract away the complicated parts of using TAPI.

**TAPI Wrapper**

http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=61

> Normally, the domain of C/C++ programmers, this wrapper code will allow you to skip all the complexity and get to work straight away.

**ATAPI - Managed TAPI wrapper for TAPI 2.0**

http://atapi.codeplex.com/

> Managed .NET library for interacting with the Microsoft Telephony API (TAPI) 2.x. This library is for creating clients that consume telephony services on Windows XP or better.

Answer (score 0):

WombatDialer does something like that for the Asterisk platform   and has powerful APIs - see http://www.wombatdialer.com/manuals/WD_UserManual-chunked/ar01s08.html

It manages the call flow internally (scheduling, error conditions) and sends HTTP notifications of events.